# Start as background process PHP built in server on Windows

Tags: php, server, localhost

I am using PHP built in server for testing and I was wondering is there a way you can hide cmd window when launching built in server using command `php -S 127.0.0.1:809 -t Folder`

I am currently working on Windows 10 so I need a Win solution.

Comment: Why do you want this? The PHP built-in server is intended for testing software during development -- it is not in any way a substitute for a real web server.

Comment: I have a really small testing project that I would try to make it look like a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create vbs script (run.vbs) and you can put this code in it

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
oShell.run "cmd /C CD resource\php && php -S 127.0.0.1:809 -t HTML", 0
Set oShell = Nothing
```

`0` in line signal for not displaying command line window.

Comment: how to stop the process?

Answer (score 0):

not hundred percent sure on this, but you might try this one from:

[What is cmd's equivalent to Bash's & (ampersand) for running a command without waiting for it to terminate?](https://superuser.com/questions/345602/what-is-cmds-equivalent-to-bashs-ampersand-for-running-a-command-without-w)

so yours could be something like:

```
start /B php -S 127.0.0.1:809 -t Folder
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I created bat file with your command and window stays open.

Comment: but you can close the window and still keep the php server running?

Comment: No. Server stops when you press close button

Comment: I created some script in Python that I don't really don't know much but it's working. Script starts server and an app. Anyway, the server is still running when I close the window.  `import subprocess
import os

def go():
 
 cwd = os.getcwd()
 path = os.path.join(cwd, "resource/php")
 subprocess.run('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --app=http://localhost:809', timeout=1000)
 os.system("cd " + path + ' & start /B php -S 127.0.0.1:809 -t HTML')
 
 
go() `

Comment: No it is not working when I close the window... perhaps a bug